# Horizontal center constraint issue in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

[image]I am having hard time in learning constraints & auto-layout in iOS.I have used any-width & any height.I have a storyboard scene on which i am adding a button & has given it some height & width.When i add horizontal center constraint then i get error for adding missing constrains. Xcode force me to reduce the width of button up-to 26 pixels & also set it's x & y position.Can somebody tell why Xcode asking me to reduce width & also changing original x & y.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you upload an image of your constraints.....

Comment: ok just add other constraints that is vertical center...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok check out the image and constraints here...

[image]

you need to give width and height constraints too....also need to give x and y position of button. so that screen knows the alignment from where to start drawing the button with how much width and height

Comment: Thanks.Can you provide me some ref. links from where i can get the details.I have been googling around a lot but proper way is not found.

Comment: Yes about auto layout.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

maybe post a picture of what your layouts look like in the story board so we can understand your problem better, but also as a rule of thumb, make sure you have constraints that will satisfy an x and y position, and a width and height, if all those are satisfied your layout wont be ambiguous. from what you have said, it sounds like you only satisfy 3 of those criteria, leaving y position out (maybe add center vertically or top space).

it may be asking you to reduce the width and height of your constraints because the value of the constraints is less than what they are in the visual representation on the storyboard, just click on the constraints and see what their value is.

Comment: why should i fix the width the height?

Comment: that seems like a weird question... but at the bottom right of the storyboard editor, there is a small button that looks like a triangle with tie-fighter wings, press that and click on update constraints after clicking on the button, see if that helps with the autolayout wanting to be 26px less

Comment: oh wait i see, so you didnt add constraints for the width and height of the button? if you dont, it will want to use the buttons intrinsic size (which just means default size based on the buttons contents) so it is trying to snap to the text of the button, you can fix that by adding width and height constraints

Answer (score 0):

The `Add Missing Constraints` error is shown because you have not provided vertical constraints, may be height constraints or vertical position constraints.

To fix this use the blue dotted guide lines to place your view and then click on "Reset to suggested Constraints" or you can provide the vertical constraints according to your requirement.

Xcode maybe warning you for button width because by default the text label of button takes the default padding space.

To add custom padding you should change the `insets` of your button contents from the storyboard.